# Conectar Nodejs Express a MySQL en Heroku

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, express, heroku

Hola amigos buenas tengan todos, hoy estoy tratando de testar la conexión de mi app con mi base de datos en heroku, estuve utilizando proSQL y Workbench para probar la conexion y no tengo ningun problema para conectarme, pero script obtengo un error.

> App listening on port 4000
>   database access deniedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306

Ya probé usando heroku login, pero por alguna razón me vota. A todo esto quiero commentar que aún no estoy haciendo el deploy, quiero hacer una conexion local a mi sql en el servidor de heroku ( ClearDB )
este es mi script

```
const mysql = require('mysql');



const {database} = require('./keys');

const pool = mysql.createPool(database);

pool.getConnection((err,conn)=>{
    if(err){
        if(err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST'){
            console.log('database connection was closed')
        }
        if(err.code === 'ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR'){
            console.log('database has to many connections')
        }
        if(err.code === 'ECONNREFUSED'){
            console.log('database access denied'+ err)
        }
    }

    if(conn){
        console.log('connection success /heroku');
        return;
    }
});

module.exports = pool;

// keys.js

require('dotenv').config()
'use strict';


module.exports = {
    database: {
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        user: process.env.DB_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_PASS,
        database: process.env.DB_DATABASE
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, ¿podrías aclarar un poco la pregunta? Hablas de Heroku, pero no has hecho el deploy, hablas de conexión local pero luego dices que a Heroku. Por favor, si puedes dar más detalles de lo que deseas hacer tal vez podríamos ayudarte. Saludos

Comment: Por otra parte, el error que te arroja significa que no encuentra el Servicio de mySQL en la dirección y puerto indicado (127.0.0.1:3306), que es normalmente la dirección local de tu propio equipo. ¿El servidor mySQL está en Heroku o en tu equipo local? Verifica eso y trata de aclararlo. Saludos

Comment: Así es quiero conectarme localmente a mi instancia de SQL (CLEARDB) que está alojada en mi app de heroku, es decir de mi app corriendo local en mi pc, pero conectado a a heroku, puedo conectarme con proSQL y workbench pero no con mi código

Comment: Prueba hardcodeando la dirección de ClearDB en tu app local, el error indica que estás tratando de conectarte a un Servidor mySQL local. Revisa los parámetros de tu archivo `.env`. Mientras tu app se ejecute en modo `development` seguro estará apuntando a un servidor mySQL local. Realiza las pruebas y comentas. Saludos

Comment: en mi .env no tengo ninguna variable 'development' solo tengo los datos de acceso , el url heroku, usuario, password, y bd

Comment: @MauricioContreras oye pues si lo hardcodeé y pues si pude conectar, pero ahorita preocupado por mi deploy , o por .env, sabes porqué no lo lee desde el .env? estoy algo confundido

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92383/discussion-between-mauricio-contreras-and-e-rawrdriguez-ophanim).